# Is there a way to prevent square brackets being inserted into my string?

Tags: apex

I seem to be getting some square brackets being inserted into my string that I am using for a dynamic SOQL query. I'm trying to check if the status of an order is one of the options chosen by the user. Usually I would be able to just throw a list after the IN clause, but because this is a string I'm not able to do so. Instead, I have a loop that iterates through the list of selected statuses and adds to the query string as needed.

I've used the exact same syntax in another org with no issues, so I'm curious as to why this would happen in another one. I've posted the version that is having the issue. Hopefully this isn't too tough to remove.

```
if(orderStatuses.size() > 0){
     query += ' AND ccrz__OrderStatus__c IN (\''+orderStatuses[0]+'\'';
     for(Integer i = 1; i < orderStatuses.size(); i++){
          query += ', \''+orderStatuses[i]+'\'';
     }
     query += ')';
}
```

What I want to have is a string that looks something like

```
'AND ccrz__OrderStatus__c IN ('Completed', 'Order Submitted')'
```

But instead I get

```
'AND ccrz__OrderStatus__c IN ('[Completed', ' Order Submitted]')'
```

I've also tried using the 'replaceAll()' method to forcibly remove them before the query is run, but they still appear anyways.

```
query.replaceAll('[\\[\\]]','');
```

When only selecting one option, it formats perfectly fine without any brackets, but once more than one is picked, this happens. 
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated on this one. As I mentioned above, this same exact code (granted with different objects, etc.) was giving me the correct results when run in a different org, so I'm stumped. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue by adding the '[' and ']' to your array "orderStatuses". If I was you, I'd look at those square brackets for your error. It is likely that the square brackets you see are literally part of the strings you're passing. There is also an extra space in the orderStatuses[1] that is further telling me you have something being added to the array you don't want earlier in the code/SQL.

```
var orderStatuses = [];
orderStatuses.push("[Completed");
orderStatuses.push(" Order Submitted]");

var query = ' AND ccrz__OrderStatus__c IN (\'' + orderStatuses[0] + '\'';
for (var i = 1; i < orderStatuses.length; i++) {
  query += ', \'' + orderStatuses[i] + '\'';
}
query += ')';

alert(query)
```